# Having Trouble running VS Code and Chrome Simultaneously

Tags: virtualbox, google-chrome

I'm having trouble running Chrome and VS Code simultaneously.

I am running 20.04.3 LTS on Oracle VM Virtualbox.

I have allocated 1 CPU out of 4, 8GB of RAM out of 16, and 64MB of video memory out of 128.

Chrome is up to date and so is VS Code.

Currently I am trying to get through The Odin Project and constantly switching between Chrome and VS Code. After a few minutes of doing this they both visually start to tweak out and things jump around the page and get stuck rending them both inoperable. I can’t click on anything and have to restart it to go back to normal.

I've done my best to explain what's happening and here's a picture:

[image: Example]

If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated because I can't continue to work constantly restarting both of these all the time. Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: Set minimum 2 CPUs, and make sure your swap is at least 4G.